# How to make tweak the performance without using the subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

A Tabel contains invoice data, I need to sum up the qty and amount based on the year as well as mothwise without using subquery

**Table1:**

```
╔════════╦═══════╦════════╦══════╗
║Month   ║ Desc  ║  Amt   ║ QTy  ║
╠════════╬═══════╬════════╬══════╬
║      1 ║  FF   ║  25.00 ║  1   ║
║      1 ║  ss   ║  55.00 ║  2   ║
║      2 ║  ss   ║  78.00 ║  3   ║
║      2 ║  FF   ║  99.00 ║  1   ║
║      3 ║  ss   ║  54.00 ║  1   ║
║      4 ║  FF   ║  58.00 ║  5   ║
║      5 ║  FF   ║  55.00 ║  2   ║
║      5 ║  ss   ║  55.00 ║  2   ║
║      1 ║  ss   ║  77.00 ║  1   ║
╚════════╩═══════╩════════╝══════╝
```

This is how i need to get the result

```
╔════════╦═══════╦════════╦══════╗══════╗
║Month   ║yearamt║  Amt   ║ QTy  ║yerQty║
╠════════╬═══════╬════════╬══════╬══════╬      
║      1 ║  556  ║  157   ║  3   ║  9   ║
║      2 ║  556  ║  177   ║  3   ║  9   ║
║      3 ║  556  ║  54    ║  1   ║  9   ║
║      4 ║  556  ║  58    ║null  ║  9   ║
║      5 ║  556  ║  110   ║  2   ║  9   ║
╚════════╩═══════╩════════╝══════╝══════╝
```

In my current query iam unable to get the yerQty column, any solution or better way to get the above result without using the subquery

```
 select  invoicedate 
,Sum(amount) over ( ) yearamoutn,Sum(amount))amount
case when DESC ='SS' and netamount <>0   then sum(Quantity) end as Quantity
from  Table1 group by invoicedate,DESC
```

Comment: why not use subquery? Homework?

Comment: NB: your query references different fields than depicted in the table definitions.

Comment: For performance Tweak not useing the subquery

Comment: my mistake for  references different fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Solution

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
    ([Month] int, [Desc] varchar(2), [Amt] int, [QTy] int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    ([Month], [Desc], [Amt], [QTy])
VALUES
    (1, 'FF', 25.00, 1),
    (1, 'ss', 55.00, 2),
    (2, 'ss', 78.00, 3),
    (2, 'FF', 99.00, 1),
    (3, 'ss', 54.00, 1),
    (4, 'FF', 58.00, 5),
    (5, 'FF', 55.00, 2),
    (5, 'ss', 55.00, 2),
    (1, 'ss', 77.00, 1)
;

SELECT DISTINCT
    [Month],
    YearAmt = SUM([Amt]) OVER(PARTITION BY 1),
    Amt = SUM([Amt]) OVER(PARTITION BY [MOnth]),
    Qty = SUM(CASE [Desc] WHEN 'SS' THEN [QTy] ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY [MOnth]),
    YearQty = SUM(CASE [Desc] WHEN 'SS' THEN [QTy] ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY 1)
    FROM @Table1
```

My Result

[image]